# How to merge nested array properties from 2 objects based on some conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to compare the below two arrays and update the status in a nested array

```
var arr1 = {
   "questionInfo": [{
         "questionId": "300002",
         "quesOptions": [{
            "optionId": "000000",
            "status": 1
         }]
      },
      {
         "questionId": "300003",
         "quesOptions": [{
               "optionId": "300015",
               "status": 1
            },
            {
               "optionId": "300016",
               "status": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
var arr2 = {
   "questionInfo": [{
         "questionId": "300002",
         "quesOptions": [{
               "optionId": "000000"
            },
            {
               "optionId": "11111111"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "questionId": "300003",
         "quesOptions": [{
            "optionId": "300016"
         }]
      }
   ]
};
```

I need to change the arr1 value to below format, I need to compare the two array and I need to update the **questionOptions** array status if the **optionId** is present in the arr2 need to update status as 1 otherwise need to update as 0

```
    var arr1 = {
        "questionInfo": [
            {
                "questionId": "300002",
                "quesOptions": [
                    {
                        "optionId": "000000",
                        "status": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "optionId":"11111111",
                        "status": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "questionId": "300003",
                "quesOptions": [
                    {
                        "optionId": "300015",
                        "status": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "optionId":"300016",
                        "status":1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

I have tried the below method, but it was not working correctly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < arr1[i].quesOptions.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i].quesOptions[j].optionId !== arr2[i].quesOptions[j].optionId) {
         arr2[i].quesOptions[j].status = 1;
      } else {
         arr2[i].quesOptions[j].status = 0
      }
   }
}
```

can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Neither arr1 nor arr2 are actually arrays.  They are objects, with an array inside them called questionInfo.  You could access the inside `optionId` with `arr1.questionInfo[i].quesOptions[j].optionId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like using `reduce` to merge the 2 inner arrays:

```js
var arr1={"questionInfo":[{"questionId":"300002","quesOptions":[{"optionId":"000000","status":1}]},{"questionId":"300003","quesOptions":[{"optionId":"300015","status":1},{"optionId":"300016","status":1}]}]},

    arr2={"questionInfo":[{"questionId":"300002","quesOptions":[{"optionId":"000000"},{"optionId":"11111111"}]},{"questionId":"300003","quesOptions":[{"optionId":"300016"}]}]}

arr1.questionInfo.forEach(q1 => {
  const q2 = arr2.questionInfo.find(q => q.questionId === q1.questionId);
  const map1 = q1.quesOptions.reduce((acc,{optionId}) => (acc[optionId] = {optionId, status:0}, acc), {})
  const map2 = q2.quesOptions.reduce((acc,{optionId}) => (acc[optionId] = {optionId, status:1}, acc), {});
    
  q1.quesOptions = Object.values({...map1, ...map2})
})

console.log(arr1)
```

First, find the equivalent value for current `q1` inside `arr2.questionInfo` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find),

Then create a `map1` object which looks like this (for `300002`) using `reduce`

```
{
  "000000": {
    "optionId": "000000",
    "status": 0
  }
}
```

As you can see, by default, we set the status to be `0`.

Similary for `q2`, create another `map2` object which has default `status` set to 1. For `300002`, it looks this

```
{
  "11111111": {
    "optionId": "11111111",
    "status": 1
  },
  "000000": {
    "optionId": "000000",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

When you merge them using spread syntax,

- If a `optionId` exists only in first, it will be taken from `map1`. So `status` will be `0`
- If `optionId` exists in both, `map2`'s value will overwrtie `map1`'s object. So, you get th one with status set to `1`
- If `optionId` exists only in the second object, it will be taken from `map2` with `status` set to `1`.

Then finally use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the merged object's values into an array.

**Update**:

If `Object.values()` is [supported in your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility), then spread syntax also [might not be supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility). You could take an alternative approach using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/assign) and `map` (This  should be added after `map2` reduce):

```
const merged = Object.assign({}, map1, map2);
q1.quesOptions = Object.keys(merged).map(function(key) {
   return merged[key];
})
```

Comment: I have used this is my code, but I am getting object.values is not a function error.

Comment: @parithiinfo which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @parithiinfo Check the update in the answer if `Object.values()` isn't supported in your browser

Comment: i have used this in node.js version 6.10

Comment: @parithiinfo check the support links I added in the "Update" section. `Object.values()` is supported only after Node 7+. You can use the alternative code I added.. `Object.assign` is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) from Node 4+. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: It was not working for dynamuic arrays , if arr1 and arr2 are different in length means it was not working

Comment: @parithiinfo If `arr1.length > arr2.length` and every item of `arr2` exists in `arr1`, then you just have to check if `q2` is null or not. If `arr2.length > arr1.length`, then you have not mentioned in the question what should be done in that scenario. Should a new `question` object be added to `arr1.questionInfo`? You need to understand the answer and customize it to your need.