# Merge arrays that was grouped by date

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, merge

I have two chat message arrays, each representing messages for a given date. I must merge these two arrays into a single object with the same date format. The object should contain all messages from both arrays, with the messages for each date merged.

Here is the data:

```
const data1 = {
  messages: {
    "27-04-2023": [
      {
        id: "SOkXFGtTwh",
      },
      {
        id: "i3NrqNyG9P",
      },
      {
        id: "lCmxr4rc5T",
      },
    ]
  }
};

const data2 = {
  messages: {
    "27-04-2023": [
      {
        id: "V9QzRgl6ji",
      },
      {
        id: "K5wfD-kX8W",
      }
    ],
    "24-04-2023": [
      {
        id: "tuarzhHPwH",
      },
      {
        id: "cbxu_dAeAj",
      },
      {
        id: "9xJpEJGUnm",
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

How to merge them to get the following output?

```
const data1 = {
  messages: {
    "27-04-2023": [
      {
        id: "SOkXFGtTwh"
      },
      {
        id: "i3NrqNyG9P"
      },
      {
        id: "lCmxr4rc5T"
      },
      {
        id: "V9QzRgl6ji"
      },
      {
        id: "K5wfD-kX8W"
      }
    ],

    "24-04-2023": [
      {
        id: "tuarzhHPwH"
      },
      {
        id: "cbxu_dAeAj"
      },
      {
        id: "9xJpEJGUnm"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

What would be the best way to perform such task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge arrays of object with nested arrays of object using JS, lodash or Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056162/merge-arrays-of-object-with-nested-arrays-of-object-using-js-lodash-or-undersco)

Comment: also [How to merge nested array properties from 2 objects based on some conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359978/how-to-merge-nested-array-properties-from-2-objects-based-on-some-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using `for-in` and spread operator to merge 2 objects of arrays:

```js
const data1 = { messages: { '27-04-2023': [{ id: 'SOkXFGtTwh' }, { id: 'i3NrqNyG9P' }, { id: 'lCmxr4rc5T' }] }};
const data2 = { messages: { '27-04-2023': [{ id: 'V9QzRgl6ji' }, { id: 'K5wfD-kX8W' }], '24-04-2023': [{ id: 'tuarzhHPwH' }, { id: 'cbxu_dAeAj' }, { id: '9xJpEJGUnm' }] }};

function merge(obj1, obj2) {
  const output = {};
  for (const key in obj1) {
    output[key] = [...(obj1[key] || []), ...(obj2[key] || [])];
  }
  for (const key in obj2) {
    output[key] = [...(obj1[key] || []), ...(obj2[key] || [])];
  }
  return output;
}

console.log({ messages: merge(data1.messages, data2.messages) });
```

Answer (score 0):

This version merges any number of such objects into one, just allowing the property value from a later object override the same-named one from an earlier one, except for `messages`, which gets special handling: grabbing all the `messages` properties, converting them into a flat list of `entries`, and folding the results back into a single object:

```js
const mergeDates = (...ds) => ({
  ... Object .assign ({}, ...ds),
  messages: ds .flatMap (d => Object .entries (d .messages)) 
               .reduce ((a, [k, vs]) => ((a [k] = (a [k] ?? []) .concat (vs)), a), {})
})

const data1 = {messages: {"27-04-2023": [{id: "SOkXFGtTwh"}, {id: "i3NrqNyG9P"}, {id: "lCmxr4rc5T"}]}}
const data2 = {messages: {"27-04-2023": [{id: "V9QzRgl6ji"}, {id: "K5wfD-kX8W"}], "24-04-2023": [{id: "tuarzhHPwH"}, {id: "cbxu_dAeAj"}, {id: "9xJpEJGUnm"}]}}

console .log (mergeDates (data1, data2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If `messages` is your only property, you can remove the `Object .assign` line.  Conversely, if you also need special handling for other properties besides `messages`, it's easy to add additional ones parallel to `messages`.